# How to loop through more than one values of select statement and perform some operations using those values in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have table called 'SalaryHead' which contains nearly 10 salary heads called as Basic, PF , HRA , ESI , IncomeTax and so on. The select statement retrieves SalaryHeads Specific for particular Employee.

Now i want to loop the Salary Heads and Perform Calculations.The salary Head Basic is the direct value exist in the table.From the Basic i have to calculate other salary Head.For example HRA is 20% of Basic and PF is 10% of HRA like that one salary head is calculated based on other salary heads.

Now i want to write a SP which contains calculations for every salary Head.But when i loop the salary heads limited to the particular employeeid(which will be passed as a parameter). Those salary heads must be calculated and summed up to give gross amount.

What is the best way to do this using stored procedure? The front end coding is not desirable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use a WHILE loop?  Along the lines of

```
WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SalaryHead WHERE Total IS NULL AND EmployeeID = @EmpID) > 0
BEGIN

  /*Calculate Salary Head */

END
```